# Polymorphic query in spring data

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have one base abstract class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_FLD")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FLD_DISCRIMINATOR", columnDefinition = "CHAR(3)")
abstract public class AbstractPassbookField
```

and some classes that extends it. For example:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
@Table(name = "P_FLD_F")
public class PassbookFileField extends AbstractPassbookField
```

and i create repository for base entity

```
public interface PassbookRepository extends CrudRepository<AbstractPassbookField, Long>
```

I'm running next test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-config.xml")
public class PassbookFieldRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    PassbookRepository passbookRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        PassbookFileField passbookFileField = new PassbookFileField();
        passbookFileField.setFilename("text.test");
        passbookFileField.setTemplate(true);
        passbookFileField.setReadonly(true);
        passbookFileField.setImageType(ImageType.I);
        passbookFileField.setResoltuionType(ImageResolutionType.N);

        passbookFileField = passbookRepository.save(passbookFileField);

        passbookRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

passbookRepository.save(passbookFileField) - works well, but
passbookRepository.findAll() gives me an exception

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [ru.teamlabs.moneybox.commons.model.passbook.field.AbstractPassbookField] : Discriminator: F ; nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [ru.teamlabs.moneybox.commons.model.passbook.field.AbstractPassbookField] : Discriminator: F
```

Quering through entityManager gives me the same error. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why it was happening.

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FLD_DISCRIMINATOR", columnDefinition = "CHAR(3)")
```

This string was the problem.

In PassbookFileField i have

```
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
```

But repository expected to get entity with discriminator with 3 chars.

Such discriminator

```
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
```

or such discriminator column definition

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FLD_DISCRIMINATOR", columnDefinition = "CHARACTER VARYING(3)")
```

solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the `DiscriminatorValue` value for your Super Class thus when retrieving it can not distinguish Super and Sub Classes. Try the following, it must work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_FLD")
@DiscriminatorValue("SF")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FLD_DISCRIMINATOR", columnDefinition = "CHAR(3)")
abstract public class AbstractPassbookField
```

Comment: It didn't help, exception remains the same.