# Why hibernate PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT annotation returns the children of a parent on a JPA findAll() search?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpql, hibernate-mapping

Let's say we have a **parent** class A and a **child** class B with the inheritance type **TABLE_PER_CLASS**.

```
@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...........
}


@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "B")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class B extends A{
    ......
}
```

And the repository

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer> {
}
```

Why is when trying to findAll() objects from A we get the objects from B too?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<A> findAllA() {
    return aRepository.findAll();
}
```

Shouldn't the @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT) force the search to return only **A** objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `B` is also an `A`. You can use jpql as a workaround to specify the concrete result type you want to fetch:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer> {

    @Query("select a from A a where type(a) = A")
    List<A> findAll();

}
```

According to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692429/polymorphic-query-in-spring-data) this will not work without `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` annotations.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance . I followed section 5 and 6. I was expecting from the explications that "@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)" should do the trick. What the author said is that: "If we don't want a sub-class to be returned by this type of query, then we only need to add the Hibernate @Polymorphism annotation to its definition, with type EXPLICIT"

Comment: Also.... your query is a bit wrong. It should be:     @Query("select a from A a where type(a) = A")

Comment: @ProgIsMetal you're right, there was a mistake. It's the way I deal with polymorphism. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked. But I still don't understand why @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT) is not enough. Did I miss some steps from this tutorial: baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance ?

Comment: @ProgIsMetal so I did answer your question, but did not deserve the bounty?

Comment: @ProgIsMetal Does baeldung tutorial work with you?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate Polymorphism annotation is counter intuitive at best. Just see all those other questions about it on Stack overflow. I'm using InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS as well in one of my projects and I can say that PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT does not really work if your base class you are querying for is a mapped entity as well. [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-polymorphism) does not state that explicitly, but still seems to imply that it was designed to work with non mapped base classes or interfaces. And that how it appears to work in my experience. That is if the base class you are querying for is @MappedSuperclass (which is what I am using) or an interface then querying for that class will obey PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT annotations on sub classes. But whenever a mapped class is being retrieved, all its mapped sub-classes will be retrieved regardless of Polymorphism annotations (and also regardless of whether this mapped class was requested directly or selected as a subclass of one requested).

To illustrate, if you have following declarations:

```
interface Base {
}

@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class A implements Base{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
...........
}

@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "B")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class B extends A{
......
}
```

Then querying for either Base or A will retrieve both A records and B records. But if you annotate A with PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT then queries for A will return both A and B records, but querying for Base won't return anything anymore as the only descendant is marked with PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT (note that B won't be returned by this query regardless of annotations on it as it is subclass of A and A is being excluded by the explicit annotation on it).

How I understand it is designed to work is this:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
...........
}

@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "A")
public class A1 extends A {
}

@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "B")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class B extends A {
......
}
```

Now queries for either A1 or A will obey PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT annotation and will only return records from table A (as instances of A1 class), but queries for class B will still query table B only. Works for me. Note that you can use an interface instead of a class with MappedSupperclass annotation and it will work the same. But either way that is not exactly same hierarchy as the one you started with.

Comment: Does this scenario happen in ```InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE```?